# Email received sent via webmail but not Javamail

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, html-email, apache-commons

I'm trying to send emails via Javamail to a corporate account.  My Java test app works fine when I send message to gmail and my personal email.  I can also successfully send to the corporate account via my email hosting webmail client.

I've read through posts here and have tried setting -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true in the VM for the test app but it did not work.

I have checked the junk mail at the corporate client and the message is not there.  That is not to say its not being blocked elsewhere at the corporate site.

Any ideas what can be causing this problem?

I'm using org.apache.commons.mail.HmtlEmail and this is the test code:

```
          // Create the email message
          HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();

          email.setHostName(smtpHost);

          email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(smtpUser, smtpPwd));

          email.setSSLOnConnect(true);

          email.addTo(to);

          email.setFrom(from);

          email.setSubject(subject);

          // set the html message
          email.setHtmlMsg(text);

          // set the alternative message
          email.setTextMsg("Your email client does not support HTML messages");

          // send the email
          email.send();
```

Comment: Any way you can check the logs of the smtp to see if anything is wrong there?

Comment: Are you sure the message is being sent successfully?  Are you getting an exception?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Comment: I have asked the hosting company to check the logs and the logs on the receiving side.  The emails are being received by other addresses so I'm assuming they go through to the corporate account and are being blocked there but won't know for sure until I hear back.  I'm wondering if there's anything I missed in the configuration of the HtmlEmail that would cause this to happen.

Comment: what  baffles me is that I can send emails from the same system and account using their web mail client or Outlook and they are received at the corporate end fine

Answer (score 0):

So @Bill's question regarding Javamail debug output got me thinking about the content of the email message.  The debug log shows all is fine but what I found was I included Bootstrap and Fontawsome JS / CSS links in the email header and that caused the message to be rejected by the corporate system for security reasons presumably.  Thanks for the help